# How to retrieve file from angular multipart/form data request in spring mvc

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I use ngFileUpload directive to send data to the client:

```
$scope.upload = function (dataUrl, formValid) {
                if (formValid && formValid === true) {
                    console.log($scope.user);
                    Upload.upload({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/user/',
                        data: $scope.setPhotoAndReturnUser(Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl))
                   .......
$scope.setPhotoAndReturnUser = function (photo) {
                $scope.user.photo.image = photo;
                return $scope.user;
            };
```

User object contains additional user information username, email etc.
This is how request looks like:

[image]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserRestController {
      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
                public ResponseEntity newUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
                    MultipartHttpServletRequest mRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
                    UserDTO user = new UserDTO(mRequest);
                    if (service.validate(user)) {
                        registrationService.register(user, request);
                        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                    }
                    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
```

My domain transfer object constructor:

```
 public UserDTO(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
                this.userEmail = request.getParameter("userEmail");
                this.userName = request.getParameter("userName");
                this.userPass = request.getParameter("userPass");
```

And this is the exception i get:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty$Access

My multipart resolver configuration:

```
@Bean
    MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
        return resolver;
    }
```

I use:
jackson-core 2.4.6
jackson-databind: 2.6.4

But i cannot fully understand what is going on, i dont have any domain objects in my method parameters, and in accordance to developer tools the request is encoded like multipart/form data. Should i instead try to use spring anonymous authentication, and split the registration process in to two different requests?

Comment: can you post your UserDTO class

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the wrong naming of the request parameters, i have to do this instead of sending all data as one object:

```
Upload.upload({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/user/',
                        file:Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl)
                        fields: {...}
```

Also i have problem with my maven dependancies , for spring 4 recomended jackson libery is

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```